# Convert a DCR video file

Tags: codec, video-conversion, video-codecs

I have a DCR (file has a .dcr extension) video file coming from a video surveillance device ( I don't know the make and model of the recorder )

I'm unable to read it with VLC, Media Player, and it won't open in Virtual Dub or can't be converted with the standard "ffmpeg.exe video.dcr output.avi" command line.

But I'm able to get a very basic** playback of the video stream with MPC-HC player of the Combined Community Codec Pack. Unfortunately, the audio stream (which I'm looking for) will not play.

According to the MPC-HC player file info, I'm dealing with this:

```
General
Format                         : MPEG-4 Visual
File size                      : 459 MiB

Video
Format                         : MPEG-4 Visual
Format profile                 : Advanced Simple@L5
Format settings, BVOP          : Yes
Format settings, QPel          : No
Format settings, GMC           : No warppoints
Format settings, Matrix        : Default (H.263)
Muxing mode                    : Packed bitstream
Width                          : 640 pixels
Height                         : 480 pixels
Display aspect ratio           : 4:3
Frame rate                     : 25.000 fps
Color space                    : YUV
Chroma subsampling             : 4:2:0
Bit depth                      : 8 bits
Scan type                      : Progressive
Compression mode               : Lossy
Writing library                : XviD 64
```

** By very basic, I mean I can play the video, but not seek through it, and there is no keyframe at all in the video output.

Hopefully some of you guys will have dealt with DCR files from video surveillance equipment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend downloading the latest version of the digital court player from http://www.bisdigital.com.  This is the program that many courts use to view video from court hearings in .dcr format.  You should be able to pause, rewind, fast forward, as well as control the speed of the video playback.

Comment: It looks like http://www.libertyrecording.com/default.htm has the same software, but perhaps with bigger version numbers, so maybe more up-to-date.